# create new File in internal storage Exception : java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Create new file in internal storage of android device but i am getting exception of No such file or directory

Here is my code:-

```
String APP_PATH_SD_CARD = "/XYZ/";
String APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD = "Demodir";
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + APP_PATH_SD_CARD + APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD;
File myFile,dir;

try {
        dir = new File(fullPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        myFile = new File(fullPath, "Vitals.txt");
        if (myFile.exists()) {
            myFile.delete();
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } else {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"File 'Vitals.txt' Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: what Android version are you testing this on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of slashes `'\'` or `'/'` use `File.seprator` for better performance.

like,

```
String APP_PATH_SD_CARD = "XYZ";
String APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD = "Demodir";

String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
+ File.seprator+APP_PATH_SD_CARD+File.seprator+APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD;
```